# Increasing length lines of shape

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, length

I am using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.8.

I have a polyline shape and I need to increase the length of all the lines 1000 meters. The lines have 2 vertex only. I need to increase the length from the last vertex.

I need to do this automatically because the shape has many lines and it is impossible to modify one by one. I have tried with Extend and Scale Tools.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: How do you like to extend your polylines? At the end, at the beginning, or on both sides?

Comment: While it should be trivially simple to add a vertex 1000 units further in an X or Y dimension, and not that much harder to add in any direction, you probably have a specific goal in mind. Please [Edit] the question to give details about that goal, and explain what software you are using, what you have tried, and what problem you have encountered.

Comment: The lines have 2 vertex only. I need to increase the lenght from the last vertex. I am using ArcGis Desktop Advanced 10.8. I have tried with Extend and Scale Tools.

Comment: Add geometry attribute start, end,  bearing. Use line from point and bearing, but populate another field by 1000 or 1000-length, depending on what you need - increase by 1000 or make it 1000 long. You might need to dissolve lines afterward.

Comment: Felix thanks for responding. I don't understand the process you propose, could you please explain it in more detail. My English is not very good, for example, I don't know exactly what "bearing" means.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I have time to do, sorry.
First tool:

[image]

Second tool:

[image]

Comment: Felix, thanks for help me. Works fine. Very clever and ingenious solution.